# How to export an ilnumerics matrix to a Microsoft® Excel® spreadsheet file?

Tags: c#, excel, ilnumerics

In c#, how can I export Ilnumerics matrix to an XLS?

With MatLab I use [Data Import and Export functions](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/data-import-and-export.html) to read and write data in spreadsheets or comma-separated value (CSV) files but I found nothing with Ilnumerics library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no special support for interfacing Office formats. We are working on an Office Plugin for one of the next (major) releases.

In the meantime, you should stick to one of the many available (free and non-free) Excel libraries. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp/2537778#2537778) for one example. On the ILNumerics side, you can fill the tables by iteratively walking your ILArrays and copying the elements over.

Comment: OK. In the meantime, I will use EPPlus (http://epplus.codeplex.com/) which according to the comments seems like an excellent library for that.